# Find permutation $B$ given $B^4 =(2143567)$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

> Let $ B\in S_7  $ and $  B^4 =(2143567)$. Find B.

How to find $B$? All I know is that $B^7 $ is identity permutation because it is a 7 cycle. So $(B^4)^2$ should be B?

---

**Reference**:

Exercise 5.31 from 'Contemporary Abstract Algebra' by Joseph A. Gallian

Comment: Let $C$ be the given permutation. Some power of $C$ will be equal to $B$... the problem is to figure out which one.

Comment: Since $B^7=id$, $B^8=B$and $B^8=(B^4)^2$

Comment: Is $ (B^4)^2$=B?

Comment: Yep got it. Thanks. I was in doubt so thanks for verifying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$B$ is a $7-$ cycle hence $B^7=I\implies B^8=B$

Now from $B^4$ find $B^8$

Comment: I have one doubt.How can we say that B is a 7-cycle?Can it have length other than 7?As it belongs to $S_7$

Comment: @ASHWINISANKHE We know that $|\beta^4|=7$ since it is a $7-cycles$. So $\beta^{28}=e$. This means $|\beta| | 28$ so $|\beta|=1,2,4,7,14,28$. it cannot be $1,2,4$ as that would mean $\beta^4=e$. You cannot get order $14,28$ by inspecting lcm's. So it has to be a 7-cycle.